MassTransit Host Configuration (no overload for method 'Host' that takes 3 args)
I was trying to set up Host Configuration to let my Dockerised microservice know where does RabbitMq run. But when I tried to specify host name, virtual host and (Username and password), as writen in the docs of MassTransit
(https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/rabbitmq#configuration)
I got an error saying that method 'Host' does not have an overload that takes 3 args. I double checked version of MassTransit NuGet (v8.3.0 for me). What am I doing wrong?
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
       cfg.Host(builder.Configuration["RabbitMq:Host"], '/', host =>
       {
           host.Username(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Username", "guest"));
           host.Password(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Password", "guest"));
       });

       cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});


Never mind. I came from Python, so the reason was so stupid. '/' is a char, which does not correspond to the function signature. It expected to get a string as a second positional argument, so the method signature matched and the code worked as intended
